# Is there a way to make Mathematica support Chemmacros of LaTeX?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, chemistry

On Mathematica 13 or later version, the `ChemicalFormula` and `ChemicalReaction` functions helpe a lot to deal with chemical formula in Mathematica, but there are still a lot limits as compared to the `Chemmacros` of LaTeX.

For example, if there is need to make plot label to as it is in LaTeX:

```latex
$$\ch{H2O}=\ch{H2}+\ch{O2}$$
```

How should I do? I tried to do this in Mathematica:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 5}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  ChemicalFormula["H2O"]["Formula"] <> "=" <> 
   ChemicalFormula["H2"]["Formula"] <> "+" <> 
   ChemicalFormula["O2"]["Formula"]]
```

But the output is

[image]

Deleting the `<>` will cause this wrong output:

[image]

Of course, they are all wrong.

Comment: Could you show full latex code which makes your latex works? Using `\usepackage{chemmacros}` it gives errors. So I used `mhchem`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your reply. `\ce` should be `\ch`, and I changed them now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do

```
lbl = Style[
   Row[{ChemicalFormula["H2O"]["Formula"], " = ", 
     ChemicalFormula["H2"]["Formula"], " + ", 
     ChemicalFormula["O2"]["Formula"]}], 20];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 5}, PlotLabel -> lbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or better

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]

SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{mhchem,upgreek}"}];
lbl=MaTeX["\ce{H2O}=\ce{H2}+\ce{O2}",Magnification->2];
Plot[Sin[x],{x,1,5},PlotLabel->lbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

For `ch` instead of `ce` then do

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{chemmacros}"}];
lbl = MaTeX["\\ch{H2O}=\\ch{H2}+\\ch{O2}", Magnification -> 2];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 5}, PlotLabel -> lbl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As your second way, when I ran it, there is `Cannot open MaTeX` `  What is the **MaTeX** and how do you know you can run it in Mathematica? Thanks

Comment: @Y.zeng Matex is a package. You need to install it first. see [MaTeXInstall](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MaTeXInstall/) it assumes you have a TeX also installed on your system. See instructions for MaTeX what it needs.

Comment: Thanks. I can run the second code now. It is really good.

Comment: The output from `MaTeX` is a graphic. So the first way may be better as they are characters which can be copied if exported as a format of **PDF**.